# BeautifulSoup doesn't parse all the elements(contents) after using request loginning to a session

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm able to log in to a session using request.

I think I'm correct because the content of the HTML being parsed is showing the result after I manually inspect the page. Below is what I've worked so far.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import lxml
from selenium import webdriver
import time

### login website

### try
login_url='https://loancare.wd.lendingsvcs.com/smagent/forms/DynamicRetry.lfcc?SMQUERYDATA=-SM-YqDWGVYPqWY8B5OeWH3aAAimesXFQJ%2fJZl7sRyuKfOaqsAKdA%2fdfrgNl5ApC3q62OYvR98r%2fBHIytJa3QlVruC7F0wmsqUXFk4lh9whGJQFJPsLSSZE1suQW3mFFgRjDcwCPdEunMEwu%2fvEglLGa1W5z5Oq8ww53oXmtxyW2hfl3mI%2foNTbyya4DpptRTu5rLC1QthHeCjvmU8Ss5PumMI96cTCefMdmFwowyYDGKMkK76h9FIe8BJFwoBECSWPsnUOK0YEAMM4XFEh6yyaJcurlgzrnWhUOjVMw9gcBwaEqw3Y0gFyT0JZ6LpjkrG%2fNfauWm8%2fdU7R6W20WHCwUUAObQgRTxBsxooG2u37kzQ%2b7vzUcgmNwoi551t27rG1zhJbFOQAh42ZfujyTiAeuveIH5uyH0C4YK%2fn5YSh5LGQ6GaCpnZR0cj7T%2b965f8f3'

### fill in headers
headers = {
"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"}

### find hidden input tags
r = requests.get(login_url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text)
itags = soup.find_all(name="input")
for tag in itags:
    print(tag)
print('\n')

### account info
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'


### fill in input tags
data = {    
"USERINPUT":username,
"PASSWORD":password,
"SMENC":"ISO-8859-1",
"SMLOCALE":"US-EN",
"UserCompany":"loancare",
"USER": "carrie.mcgahan,o=loancare",
"smauthreason":"0",
"smagentname":"sKydreaDKgXaN3m7DBUPd3z8oTpsSTRHjK/Eb2ArY4ip5nyfodVHKy8fvnIR3ghL",
"postpreservationdata":""
     }

### start session.
session = requests.session()

### login
r = session.post(url=login_url, headers= headers, data=data)
# print(r.url)
print('\n')

### try one link first
scrape_url ='https://loancare.wd.lendingsvcs.com/webdirect/WebDirect.html#taskListView?loanNumber=24832974&clientId=623&providerName=loancare&systemId=prod'

### request page want to scrape.
url = session.get(url=scrape_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
time.sleep(10)

print(url.status_code)
print('\n')

print(url.url)
print('\n')

print(url.content)
print('\n')

soup = bs(url.text,'lxml')
print(soup)

print('finished')


session.close()
```

The issue is the parsed page doesn't show all the tags but it shows parts of the tags in below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Web Direct</title>
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma" />
<meta content="-1" http-equiv="Expires" />
<meta content="-1;URL=../index.html" http-equiv="Refresh" />
<meta content="IE=11" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<link href="webdirect/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/gxt-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="WebDirectApp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" 
/>
</head>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#loading {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 40%;
    margin-left: -45px;
    padding: 2px;
    z-index: 20001;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#loading a {
    color: #225588;
}

#loading .loading-indicator {
    background: white;
    color: #444;
    font: bold 13px tahoma, arial, helvetica;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
}

#loading .loading-indicator img {
    margin-right: 8px;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#loading-msg {
    font: normal 10px arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
<div id="loading">
    <div class="loading-indicator" style="text-align: center;"><img height="32" src="images/default/shared/large-loading.gif" style="margin-right:8px;float:left;vertical-align:top;" width="32" /><span id="loading-msg" style="font-size: 10pt;"><br/>Loading WebDirect...</span></div>
</div>
<!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
<iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" src="javascript:''" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
<script src="webdirect/webdirect.nocache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/rsa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

The correct content I hope to parse is like in the screenshot next to the blue ink.

[image]

Then I found the content I have is different than the content in the picture. 
I have

```
<div id="loading">
```

But the picture has

```
<div id="x-auto-6">
```

I've tried using different parsers like lxml and html5lib but still don't work out for me. Any suggestions? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The fact that there is a "loading" indicator indicates to me that the page loads asynchronously, AFTER the initial HTML request. If this is the case, then you will need to use a browser automation tool like selenium instead of requests/bs4

Comment: @G.Anderson Do you think if I can wait for all the pages load? I tried but still wanna ask if it's approachable.

Comment: The requests module has no way to do this. You can use Selenium, which automates a browser session instead of sending http requests, and _does_ allow you to wait for elements to load on the page.

Comment: @G.Anderson I see what you meant. Thank you for the hint.